# Add DIR to application dir Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, directory-structure

I whant to use some classes that are not part of ZF. I have a dir classes in application dir
and the classes dir contains classes that are required as object or static. In Bootstrap i "load" every class.php.

```
Zend_Loader::loadFile('TimeZones.php', APPLICATION_PATH.'/classes/', false);
```

How can I have all the classes by default loaded/included from this dir?

---

**SOLUTION** for now. in Bootstrap.php

```
$files = scandir(APPLICATION_PATH.'/classes/');

foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file[0] != '.') {
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($file, APPLICATION_PATH.'/classes', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add your dir to the include_path where PHP looks for files.

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 
                  APPLICATION_PATH.'/classes/' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To have your classes loaded automatically from that dir, place it in your include_path.  [Here's two ways to do that](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-set-php-include-path-in-php-ini-file/).  Setting `include_path` directly in your PHP.ini, if at all possible, is recommended.

Comment: that would be a global path, i dont want that.